# SQL Server database in a Visual C++ application

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have to create a application in Visual C++ which accesses a SQL database, selects and inserts data.

I know it is very easy in C# but it has to be written in C++. I prefer to use MS SQL Server 2012 because it is the only DBMS I know. Also I have to use Visual Studio.

Could you please tell me what is the best way to deal with this problem? 
I need a relatively easy way because I'm not an experienced programmer.

Comment: MFC?  Then 'ODBC' with `CRecordset`/`CDatabase` derived classes is the easiest (not necessarily best) way.

Answer (score 1):

what kind of visual c++ do you want use? if you use .Net you can use ADO.Net
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ctka9db.aspx

Comment: I dont know if I told you the truth :) I use Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, and use the C++ programming language. I thought Visual C++ is a variant of C++ but I see its only the IDE.

Comment: In VS2012 you can develop visualc++(WINRT) and visualc++/cli  and MFC and win32 and C++ . you can  use ADO.net with WINRT and C++/Cli.